# Is EE Stack a free design and advice website?

Tags: discussion, support

More than half of the questions asked on this site seem to be either review/fix my design ([Example](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/399929/opinions-on-what-ive-come-up-with-for-a-12-v-to-5-v-automotive-circuit)) or I don't know how to design, please help me design it ([Example](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/400877/designing-brake-light-with-specific-luminous-intensity)). Is EE Stack a free design assistance forum?

I'm slightly confused what is supposed to be asked on stack? I thought the whole idea of Stack was to ask generic, reusable questions to create a database.

I understand specific design questions may require design help ect, but the vast majority seem to be 'Design this thing for my Uni project/hobby project ect'. Which I expect is the reason that whenever you go to 'active' the vast majority of questions come from people who have >50 rep and are never seen again.

Can experienced members please clarify?

Comment: The key is that the question must be narrow enough. Asking something like "how do I design this whole product" is entirely too broad and will be closed. Rather, a decent design question will ask "I'm designing product x for which I will need component y. I have checked on various component y and it seems like they have different voltage specs and on-resistance [examples, links to datasheets, possibly schematics]. Which one would be most suitable for task z, given that I need [list of requirements]?"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Yes!

It is most definitely a free *advice* website, and do not share your experience that the majority of the question are "design this thing".

Pure "design this for me" questions are not received kindly. You mention "free", but there is no [free lunch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_ain%27t_no_such_thing_as_a_free_lunch) - you pay with your time by researching your question and making sure that it contains necessary information. However, the purpose of this stack is to *help* people trying to design electronic circuits, so *advice* questions are absolutely on topic.

Neither of the questions you link to are "design this for me" questions, not even close. In each of them, the user has done the work and/or research, is stuck on a specific part, and need advice from more experienced designers - exactly what this is all about!

To answer your question about being "generic": Personally both of those questions are questions I have asked myself at one time or another, when thinking about different projects. I expect that I will have use for both of them when it's time for me to buy a car, because the one I want is pretty old and I will probably want to build both new brake lights and internal 5V electronics.

Comment: This is a pure  "design this for me" question: *[How do I design a circuit to convert a 100 mV and 50 Hz sine wave to a square wave?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/432206)*. It just states the requirements and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't really matter what kind of question it is or how much rep you have, if it's not on topic then the question will be closed.

It also helps to have a well written question, and ask a specific question so people know how to answer.